# fetch multiple kind of data

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

I'm building an e-commerce website and I use fetch API to fetch the product details and the product photos from the same form to the same URL .

like so

```
await fetch('/host', {

     method: 'POST',
     body: fd

     }).then(

    fetch('/host', {
        
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({

            title: title,
            category: category,
            hostKind: hostKind,
            area: area,
            realstateDesc: realstateDesc,
            neighbourhood: neighbourhood,
            governorate: governorate,
            city: city,
            address: address,
            zipCode: zipCode,
            allowed: allowed,
            maxnum: maxnum,
            timeper: timeper,
            additional: additional,
            price: price,


        })



    })
)
```

the question is there any way to fetch them in same fetch code .

notice that

```
1- the body and the headers are different .
2- I use the fetch for photos to fetch to a middleware
```

Comment: You can program the server to return that data together with one request, yes. This is not so much a JavaScript `fetch()` question as it is a "**how do I properly design a PHP REST server**".

Comment: @RandyCasburn weird to assume PHP

Comment: Why do you want to combine the requests?

Comment: @Evert - OMG - yes, totally weird. I must have kludged two questions together in my feeble mind! Anyway, this is clearly a server/endpoint issue.

Answer (score 1):

On the client-side, you can join multiple promises into one.
This can be done using [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) API.

```js
const options1 = {method: 'POST', body: someData}
const options2 = {method: 'POST', headers: someHeaders, body: anotherData}

const requests = [fetch('/host', options1), fetch('/host', options2)]

const [response1, response2] = await Promise.all(requests)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as the OP is asking how to get both sets of data with one request, not with two.

Comment: @jfriend00 to be fair I think the question could be interpreted in a few different ways. The grammar isn't perfect and I also didn't get "Combine multiple requests together".

Comment: yeah, I should've been clarifying the question first

Answer (score 0):

Adding the image as a base64 encoded String inside your server side script, will allow it to pass it in a JSON object.

You can then set the image on the reply with something similar to:

```
document.getElementById("imagePlaceholder").src =
  `data:image/jpeg;base64,${reply.base64imageString}`);
```

On the server side you could modify the requests into an array-like parser and then reply to every request in the same order. This would allow you to easily handle multiple requests at once.

Example Client Side:

```
fetch("/host", {
  ...,
  body: [photoRequestStuff, dataRequestStuff]
}).then(data => {
  data.forEach((dataset, index) => {
    // index 0 should now be the picture and index 1 the data stuff.
  })
})
```